# fatal: fetch-pack: unable to fork off sideband demultiplexer

Tags: git, magento, github, ssh

We're working on a clients Magento website at the moment. We've been developing some updates on http://dev.theirwebsite.com and using git to track commits etc. We got to the stage today when we were happy to put all of the changes live onto their production website on a Linux server.

We went to the root folder of their site via SSH and ran a 'git pull' command to pull in the master file (git pull 'origin' master) but got the following error back:

```
error: cannot create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
fatal: fetch-pack: unable to fork off sideband demultiplexer
```

I've been looking all day for ways to fix this. Just to clarify, the dev.theirdomain.com works with git pull, but the production site (even though it's on the same server) doesn't...

Answer (score 6):

Your system is out of resources -this is why rebooting worked for you.

Just keep an eye on your running processes and kill the one thats hogging all the memory and you won't need to reboot next time this happens.

Comment: This happened to be the case when I encountered this.  `free -m` revealed that there was little memory left and then I killed the processes which were using the most memory, and then `git pull` worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your system and rebooting. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try it and post if it works!

It's a site that's been in development for sometime, It's on a shared linux server with linux on so I'm guessing there will have been some system updates anyway. It's the second time it's happened on this server but I'll try to push something through tomorrow and see if it's working again.

Very odd issue.